# Android telnet communication

Tags: android, wifi, communication, telnet, gsm

I am developing an android app to for a university project. The app is supposed to control a autonomous robot over a long distance and on the site. The commands received and sent to the robot are basically a string of binary. For the long range I am using GSM and everything is working as supposed. Now for the short range the robot a wifi router (it's a pretty big robot) to which I am supposed to connect and communicate over telnet. Could you help me, I have no idea where to start on the telnet part.
Thanks

Comment: I think you need to give a little more info - what type of Robot if it a publicly available one, does the Robot have a Telnet client built in that you want to communicate with or do you have to develop it? If the latter what is the Robot dev environment?

Comment: Thanks anyway I already solved the problema. By the way it is a robot built by us